# Radio buttons can multiple select and label cannot to display in 1 row problem

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I have a problem with the radio button put in the bootstrap format. And label with radio cannot put in the same line. Below is my coding:

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Individual</label>                                                    
<input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" id="individual" name="individual" value="" title="Individual">

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Company</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" id="company" name="company" value="" title="Company">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
<label>SPANCO</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" id="spanco" name="spanco" value="" title="SPANCO">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My result is shown like below picture, radio button why can select multiple ticks, and label with a button cannot be 1 line:

[image: output1]

I want the expected result is shown like below:

[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

for aligning label and checkbox in same line you should add d-flex and
align-items-center

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>Individual</label>                                                    
    <input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" 
      id="individual" name="individual" value="" title="Individual">
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" id="company" name="company" value="" title="Company">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>SPANCO</label>
    <input type="radio" class="form-control <?php echo $class_mandatory; ?>" 
          id="spanco" name="spanco" value="" title="SPANCO">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```